# 5.1.7 Hera - awful battery performance

Tags: release-hera, nvidia, battery

Hi I just installed elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera, and my battery lasts 10min.

My laptop:
Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
8,1 GB memory

I was using loki before that, and I could watch a movie (720p - 2 hours), now it's 10min with screen on.

Previous installation I had nothing special installed for the battery.

Do you have any idea what I might do to fix that?

Thank you

Comment: Hmm... I'd start with TLP. You *shouldn't* have to do anything more than install it. If you do find you need to do more, you can poke around in the settings. This is a good link: https://linrunner.de/tlp/ Let us know how that works out for you. It's just `sudo apt install tlp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the latest version of [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/#) using it's PPA following the steps below from [this blog post](https://www.jwillikers.com/power-management-on-linux-with-tlp).

1. Install the necessary package for easily adding PPA’s.

```
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
```

2. Add the TLP PPA to your system to get the latest version of TLP.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -uy ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

3. Install TLP.

```
sudo apt -y install tlp tlp-rdw
```

4. TLP will start automatically at boot, but to start it now without rebooting, do so manually.

```
sudo tlp start
```

Comment: well thank you, it seems to work. I could watch a whole movie being unplugged. weird thing though, I still get an alert I have low battery really quickly, but then nothing.